# Error handling of an object in C#

Tags: .net, json, error-handling

This is probably simple, but I have a .asmx web service that returns an object serialized as json.  If there is an error, I would like to throw a string.  I ended up adding a Public String for the error message.  Can I cast my object in order to return a string?

```
public TmsObject GetTombstoneDataJson(string ObjectNumber)
{
    if ((Regex.IsMatch(ObjectNumber, @"^([\w\._-]|\s)*$")))
    {
        try
        {
            TmsObject tmsd = new TmsObject();

            tmsd.Dated = "foo";
            tmsd.Medium = "foo";
            tmsd.Dimensions = "foo";
            tmsd.ObjectNumber = "foo";
            tmsd.CreditLine = "foo";

            return tmsd;
        }
        catch
        {       
            TmsObject notmsd = new TmsObject();  
            notmsd.ErrorMsg = "There was an error in processing this request.  Please review the web service description and try again.";
            return notmsd;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TmsObject notmsd = new TmsObject();
        notmsd.ErrorMsg = "One of the required parameters is empty or incorrect.";
        return notmsd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the return type of the method to `string`. But, I don't think you want to do that. Anyway, the `ErrorMsg` string is already returned as part of your object. So, it would be up to the caller to check if `ErrorMsg` contains anything before proceeding.